# Init is a not a function

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver-io

I have one application which are used node js. In which I have used selenium webdriverIO for testing purpose but when I write a script using selenium webdriverIO it and using INIT function it will generate error **"TypeError:INIT is not a function"**. Please give solution for this code

> TypeError: webdriverio.remote(...).init is not a function
>           at Object. (E:\WebdriverIOAutomation\test\specs\WithoutWdioClient.js:11:6)
>           at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
>           at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
>           at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
>           at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
>           at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
>           at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
>           at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
>           at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)

```
var webdriverio = require('webdriverio');

var options = {
    desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome'
    }
};

webdriverio
    .remote(options)
    .init()
    .url('http://www.google.com')
    .title(function(err, res) {
        console.log('Title was: ' + res.value);
    })
    .end();
```

**Expected Result:** Get Title of Google
**Actual Result:** Generate Error of INIT Function

Comment: I beleive `webdriverio.remote(options)` returns a Promise - so you'll need to read the documentation

Comment: yes..both are different but how can i solve that it is not a function ?

Comment: hi I write this code now it will generate in .end...This is not a function

Comment: It is also generate error

Comment: No return any value

Comment: title is generate error title is not a function.Please send whole code

Comment: when I run this code it will display..2019-04-09T06:10:48.363Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://0.0.0.0:4444/wd/hub/session
2019-04-09T06:10:48.367Z INFO webdriver: DATA { capabilities:
   { alwaysMatch: { browserName: 'chrome' }, firstMatch: [ {} ] },
  desiredCapabilities: { browserName: 'chrome' } }

Comment: What version of webdriver-io do you use?